# Rails, session and rendering partial with session variables via AJAX, have to work but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session

I have a button, when I click on it, liked product ID is stored in the session. Everything happens through AJAX.

At the bottom of the page I want to see saved products and want they updated automatically via jQuery. But div appears only if I refresh the page.

Everything seems to be correct, but does not work.

My link:

```
<%= link_to "", remember_url(prop.id), method: :post,
                            id: 'remember_me',
                            class: "like #{like prop.id}",
                            data: { href: remember_url(prop.id)},
                            remote: true %>
```

My method in controller:

```
 def remember_me
   session[:product] ||= []
   products_array = session[:product]
   product = Product.find(params[:id])
   if products_array.include? product.id
     products_array.delete(product.id)
   else
     products_array << product.id
   end
   #redirect_to :back
   #render :nothing => true
   render partial: "static_pages/debag" #=> this is going to be "result" in AJAX.
 end
```

render partial: 'static_pages/debag:

```
<%= session[:houses] %>
```

ajax:

```
$('a.like').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('href'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(){
                suppose here I have to refresh session?
                $(".session").html("<%= j(render(partial: 'static_pages/debag')) %>"); 
            }
        });
    });
```

---

Solution:
Answer was weird. But now it's working. Just added result to function and into html.

```
$('input#start_page, a.like').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('href'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result){

                $(".session").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a template named like remember_me.js.erb in appropriate controller's views folder

and paste this code in it.

```
$(".session").html("<%= j render partial: 'static_pages/debag' %>");
```

Comment: already tried, nothing. Suppose I have to refresh session varriables when making ajax call.

Comment: @FastIndy then you have to give me more information like some part of development log that include sending request.